# WCF Web services and Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wcf, mobile, service

Just a quick question as I'm struggling to get my Web Service working.
Basically I followed a tutorial as I'm new to Windows Phone and Databases,

```
"http://studentguru.gr/b/dt008/archive/2010/12/02/querying-a-database-on-windows-phone-7-using-wcf.aspx"
```

However i'm using my own database, a .sdf file created in visual studio

I managed to create the service, the references and all the methods it said to make.
However when I try to grab the data from the service at runtime it just returns

```
       Timesheet_System.Servicereference.TimeData
       Timesheet_System.Servicereference.TimeData
       Timesheet_System.Servicereference.TimeData
       Timesheet_System.Servicereference.TimeData
```

For all 4 of the items in the database.

Does anyone know a reason why?
Thanks a lot.
Code Below:

I have a data service in an asp.net site, and an ado.net data model,
then i have  a service reference in the phone app and 2 methods to call data
 This is the data service code in the asp.net application

```
namespace TimesheetDataSite
{
     [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [SilverlightFaultBehavior]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =     AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1
{
    [OperationContract]
    public List<TimeData> DoWork()
    {
        // Add your operation implementation here
        using (TimeDataEntities2 entities = new TimeDataEntities2())
        {
            var alldata = from x in entities.TimeDatas select x;
            return alldata.ToList();
        }
    }

    // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
}
```

}

the 2 methods in the phone app

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        Service1Client client = new Service1Client();

        client.DoWorkCompleted +=
            new EventHandler<DoWorkCompletedEventArgs>(client_DoWorkCompleted);
        client.DoWorkAsync();
    }
    void client_DoWorkCompleted(object sender, DoWorkCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {

            listBox1.ItemsSource = e.Result;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your code so we can help.

Comment: Done, If it helps what im trying to do is  have a page that gets the information from the database. And another page that records time, and sends it off to the database.

Comment: The issue is your `ListBox` doesn't know what to do with the `TimeData` type, so it simply calls `.ToString()` on each instance. Unfortunately I don't currently have Visual Studio on this machine but I'd suggest trying to add the line `listBox.DisplayMember = "<the property you want to display in the box>"`.

Comment: How would that be presented then, like using the SQL attribute name such as ID?

Comment: check out my answer. As you haven't given us the definition of `TimeData` I have just made up some property names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TimeData As per my comment, try the following:

```
void client_DoWorkCompleted(object sender, DoWorkCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        listBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "PropertyA";
        listBox1.ItemsSource = e.Result;
    }
}
```

Where `PropertyA` is the name of the property on `TimeData` that you want to display.

Like I said, I don't have Visual Studio available to test this but it should work.

Comment: I keep getting " does not contain  a definition for valuemember and displaymember  which is weird. Sorry for being such a pain, im very new to windows phone

Comment: Wow! I still get what i said but i used listBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Username"; and that worked, so if i wanted to get the username, hours worked , date and id, would i just copy the same statement?

Comment: I think to display more complex values (i.e. a composite of properties like you said) you'd need to look into `DataTemplate`s.

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel. It's all sorted now. I just have to send to the DB now  I've +1'd and accepted, is there anything else you may need to bump your score up?